# MongoDB failed to connect connection timed out: Connects via Atlas

Tags: mongodb

When starting my app, I get the following error:

```
error: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection timed out
    backend_1     |       at connectionFailureError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:342:14)
    backend_1     |       at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:310:16)
    backend_1     |       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    backend_1     |       at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    backend_1     |       at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:483:8)
    backend_1     |       at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    backend_1     |       at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)]
    backend_1     |       at Pool.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
    backend_1     |       at Pool.emit (events.js:315:20)
    backend_1     |       at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14
    backend_1     |       at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:995:11
    backend_1     |       at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
    backend_1     |       at callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:280:5)
    backend_1     |       at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:310:7)
    backend_1     |       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    backend_1     |       at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    backend_1     |       at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:483:8)
    backend_1     |       at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    backend_1     |       at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7),
```

However, I can connect to the MongoDB service via MongoDBCompass and the Database connection tool in WebStorm, using the same connection string. "mongodb://localhost:27017/fmis"

I'm struggling to find the root cause to even try and solve it myself.

Update: as asked in the comments, I am running docker

Comment: Are you running this with Docker compose?

Comment: Yes...Does it interfere with Node-Mongo connection and not the database applications - Mongo connections?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by including the following in my connection configuration:

```
mongoose.connect(
    db,
    {
        ...
        useUnifiedTopology: true   //THIS SETTING
    })
    ...
)
```